# Python loop through excel sheets, add sheetname to list, then concat all

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am looping through Excel worksheets and appending them to a list. When the loop finishes, I use Pandas to concat to a single dataframe. The problem I'm having is adding the worksheet name into the appropriate list.

```
# infile is a filepath variable    
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(infile, on_demand=True)



dfList = []
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names():
    df = pd.read_excel(infile, sheet_name, header = 0)
    #df['Well_name'] = sheet_name
    dfList.append(df)
    print(sheet_name + " appended.")
    #time.sleep(2)
print("Loop complete")
# Concatenating the appended lists
dfs = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0)
```

I tried creating a new column in df but that created a length mismatch and it also didn't work because it was constantly rewritten to the last worksheet name in the loop.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are meeting some scoping issues. One way to avoid this problem is to use a list comprehension. You can also use `pd.DataFrame.assign` to add a series within your list comprehension:

```
dfList = [pd.read_excel(infile, sheet_name, header=0).assign(Well_name=sheet_name) \
          for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names()]

dfs = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp this did exactly what I wanted!